# Force Android splash screen on Portlait mode by Titanium

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I made application which has four tabas and one uses camera function.

This tab needs both portlait/landscape.
Other three tabs use only porlait mode.

Now I set like this for iOS

in tiapp.xml

```
<ios>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
```

then in app.js

Force orientation like this.

```
tabWin1.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT];
tabWin2.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT];
tabWin3.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT];
tabWin4.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT,Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT,Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT];
```

It works perfect.
Even I hold iPhone landscape and start application, splash screen is forced to portlait mode.

Now I want to do the same thing for in Android

in tiapp.xml

I set like this.

```
<application>
    <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiTranslucentActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiModalActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"/>
    <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.TiTabActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name="ti.modules.titanium.ui.android.TiPreferencesActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>            
</application>
```

However it doesn't force the splash screen in portlait mode.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What Activity does the splash screen use?

Comment: Good question @JohnP. The above list does not include the main activity (the one named after your app). Maybe try that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want locking the Splash screen in Portrait mode, you must lock the Android Activity (follow this step : http://bencoding.com/2016/02/11/android-orientation-locking-for-titanium/).

But ! If you do this, your entire app will be lock in Portrait. I don't think there is way to lock the splashscreen in Portrait mode and set a Window to Landscape mode after (it's explain here : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Orientation-section-29004932_Orientation-LimitingorientationmodesonAndroid)

Comment: I understood It is impossible lock splash screen Portrait while application has both. Thank you very much.